# Javascript, count how many files were attached to a file upload input

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, file-upload

I have this file input:

```
<input type="file" name="photo[]" multiple="yes">
```

What I want is, when someone uploads a file/files to it, I want to alert them how many files were uploaded (altogether). Like if I upload 3 files, it will alert "3 files were uploaded". And if I add 2 more files it will alert "5 files were uploaded" (adding the 2 files uploaded before).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var numFiles = $("input:file")[0].files.length;
```

Answer (score 4):

you may try this too

```
document.forms["form_name"]["multi_files_input_name[]"].files.length
```

Comment: its more accurate than previous